# GCS resumable uploads speed

Tags: java, python, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a question concerning upload speed to Google Cloud Storage using resumable uploads.
I've wrote a desktop java client to upload large files to GCS(it has some specialized features thats why gsutil was not an answer for my company). During tests runs about 2 months ago it was utilizing available connection bandwidth very well with about 20Mbps out of 25Mbps connection. The project was frozen for almost 2 months and now when it is reopened the same client is uploading with very poor speed at about 1.4Mbps out of 25Mbps availible.
I've wrote simple Python script to check if it will have same problems and it is a little faster but still at about 2Mbps. Gsutil tool is performing almost the same like my Python script.
I've also run the test on different network infrastructure with over 50Mbps upload speed.

The results are also quite poor:

- Java client 2.4Mbps
- Python script 3.2Mbps
- gsutil 3.2Mbps

The only thing that have changed is the Google Cloud Storage API version. I'm using JSON API and the first tests were run on v1beta API version.
At the moment there's no difference if I'm still using depreciated API or the new one.

Has anyone encountered same upload speed degradation?

What are your average upload speeds?

What could be a possible reason of such a dramatic upload performance decrease?

Will parallel uploads of composite objects help me to fully utilize available bandwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ascertain what the highest bandwidth you can expect is, we suggest running the [gsutil perfdiag](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/perfdiag) command.

For example, to see how well it uploads a 100 MB file:

```
gsutil perfdiag -t wthru -s 100M gs://bucketname
```

This will upload a 100MB file five times and report the results. An example output from my run:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Write Throughput                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied a 100 MB file 5 times for a total transfer size of 500 MB.
Write throughput: 71.61 Mbit/s.
```

It will also output lots of other information that might help diagnose the problem. If the perfdiag output shows much higher throughput than your application, then something might be wrong with your code. If the perfdiag output is also low bandwidth, then something might be wrong with your network path to Google's servers, which the perfdiag output can help identify the problem. If that doesn't help solve your problem, please email the result file (`perfdiag -o output.json`) to gs-team@google.com.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was very helpful for me. 
I was unable to run the perfdiag -t wthru command on gsutil version 4.5 because it was throwing `'NoneType' object is not callable.` exception (I've noticed that test files were present in GCS bucket despite error). The lat and rthru were running without problems.
I managed to run the test on gsutil 4.2 uploading 100M files.
The results for single thread were the same as for my Python script at about 3.2Mbps.
I've also made a test run for 4 threads and it managed to upgrade upload speed to over 8Mbps.

Comment: The test results mean that my code is OK and I have problems with my network connection.
I wonder why there was such a big difference during tests run on same network infrastructure 2 months ago. 
Do you have any suggestions what could I possibly check in the logs I have to recognize the cause of limited upload speed to Google servers or should I send you the json log files?
Once again thank you for help.

Comment: Any chance you're not in the US? If you're in the EU, make sure you're writing to an EU bucket. Otherwise, try a trace route to storage.googleapis.com

Comment: Well, that's right. I'm in EU and I did not provide a location constraint while creating a bucket. I'll try to create a EU bucket and let know if it helps. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm..I've created new bucket with location constraint "EU" but it did'n help a bit. Upload speeds are same as before.

Comment: I've also run a tracert command on both storage.googleapis.com and the googserv_hostnames from the gsutil perfdiag log file. 
For storage.googleapis.com there are 17jumps, 10 of which have over 100ms.
For the ip from googserv_hostnames there are 14 jumps, 9 of which have over 30-40ms.

Comment: Do you have any further suggestions what can I do?